# How to make view cache unlimited in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, caching, view

I know how to specify time for view caching in cakephp as:

```
$cacheAction = array(
    'index' => '1 hour',
    'search' => '10 minutes',
    'view' => '2 days'
    );
```

How can I make it for unlimited time?

Answer (score 1):

Set a very long duration like `'+99 years'` which will certainly exceed your app's lifetime.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe my question was not clear. I was not looking for a solution to keep the view cached for a long time, that's quite obvious, but a 'keyword' for unlimited time, if any